# Full protection from shell-script injections (like a "Bash injection") - Is it even possible?

Tags: injection, bash, cms

Assume there's a website built with some FOSS CMS (like Drupal) and the websites' directory is owned and grouped by `root` (instead `www-data` as common in Apache in Nginx) and a friend of the site's owner mistakenly sees that and tells the owner:

> Beware that if an hacker finds a way to inject shell code
>   through inodes in that sites directory it could destroy your server and this code will run without problem because the inodes are are owned and grouped by root.

I wonder if such "shell scripting injection" attack even possible.

Let's even assume the owner now creates a usual user like (say, by the name of "`Boobinio`") and runs:

```
chown boobinio /var/www/html/mysite -R && chgrp boobinio /var/www/html/mysite
```

I still can't see how it fully protects the owner because if the hacker knows this user "boobinio" (and I guess there are several ways to discover it) then it could try to inject shell code when it's plausible that the owner is in **active sudo**, and then, where's the total difference between this case, to a case of shell injection when the owner is in **active root**?

### My question:

If I'm accurate in what I just described, what can anyone do to ensure not to have shell injections on the CMS when either working as active sudo or active root?

Comment: I don't understand the attack. Does the attacker create a new file containing bash code? How is this then executed?

Comment: From what I could grasp on the discussion on this in a Hebrew Facebook group the attack is this: An hacker manages in some way to execute a command on the webserver after finding a breakage in the website and thus destroyed the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it does not matter what the owner of group of *files* is (unless they are setuid). What matters is that this is a hint that the application could be run as root which **is** a security threat.

The rules are:

- the web application should be runned as a non priviledged user - in particular, that user should never be allowed to sudo!
- it should only have write access to the files this must be written or changed by the application
- all other files (static) should only be readable and should belong to another (admin) user

Comment: F. Hauri gave a good remark about the `www-data` user common for Apache and Nginx as for 2018. This user especially shouldn't have `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The fact a directory or a file is owned by *root* don't give root privilege to people who access them. (Unless *`suid`* bit are set). Having files and directories owned by *root* ensure nothing won't be written by another user, unless changing permission to `777` (full permissions for everybody).
2. The user who serve web (mostly *www-data* through any webserver) must not be able to run `sudo`! I they just could read some dirs and files, this must be enough.
3. As [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is know for regular security flaw, you have to use another [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) (like `csh`, `dash` or even `ksh`)  as default shell (link to `/bin/sh`).

Some refresh about files and directories permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

There is a 1st sign that could be `-` for a file, `d` for a directory, `l` for a symlink, `b` for a block device or `c` for a character device.

Then 3 group of 3 signs

```
Type User Group Other
   d  rwx   rwx   rwx
```

For each group:

- `r` mean file or directory is readable by [User,Group,Anybody]
- `w` mean file or directory is writeable by [User,Group,Anybody]
- `x` mean file is executable by ...
  or mean directory is *accessible* by ...

So, for sample:

```
drwxr-xr-x /var
drwxr-xr-x /var/www
drwx--x--x /var/www/mysite
-rw-r--r-- /var/www/mysite/myfile.txt
```

Anybody would by able to read `myfile.txt`, but won't be able to

- modify this file
- execute this file (exept for php under web server)
- delete this file
- read, modify or delete the directory `mysite`. (so accessing `/var/www/mysite/myhidden-dc22e606-a281-410c-be4f-df6b2ea175d9.txt` is *reserved*... Care to only use *`https`* for this kind of tricks.)

Care about `setuid` and `setgid` bits, have a look at [GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools Summary / File Permissions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x9543.htm)